# subClassOf and instance of RDF rdfs:Class

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology, rdfs

[In RDFS](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_classes), all things are instances of `rdfs:Resource`. All other classes are subclasses of `rdfs:Resource`. And `rdfs:Resource` is an instance of `rdfs:Class`.

My question is: Could any one help explain this paragraph above? I am confused about this subclass and instance and why they have that relationship.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three parts here:

> All things are instances of rdfs:Resource.

Yup, everything is a resource.  You, me, the value true, etc.  Everything is a resource.  Resource is the catch-all class of everything.

> All other classes are subclasses of rdfs:Resource.

The word "other" here might be misleading, since rdfs:Resource is an rdfs:Resource too, since every class is a subclass of itself.  But yes, every class is a subclass of rdfs:Resource.  X is a subclass of Y when being an instance of X implies being an instance of Y.  Since everything is an rdfs:Resource, then for *any* class X, if something is an X, that same thing is also an rdfs:Resource.  (In a sense, this is trivial.)

> rdfs:Resource is an instance of rdfs:Class.

Yes.  Everything that is a class is an instance of rdfs:Class.  rdfs:Resource is a class, so it's an instance of rdfs:Class.

If you want to think in terms of triples, the above mean that

1. For all x, we have the triple: [x rdf:type rdfs:Resource].
2. For all x, we have the relationship: *if* [x rdf:type Class] *then* [x rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:Resource].
3. We have the triple: [rdfs:Resource rdf:type rdfs:Class].

You don't mention it in the question, but I wonder if this may be confusing because it leads to the situation that we have all of the following:

- [rdfs:Resource rdf:type rdfs:Class]
- [rdfs:Class rdf:type rdfs:Resource]
- [rdfs:Class rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:Resource]

These might look a little bit odd, but looking at their meaning, they all seem acceptable:

- resource is a class (i.e., rdfs:Resource is the kind of thing that something can be; it makes sense to say "x is an rdfs:Resource").
- class is a resource (everything's a resource!)
- every class is a resource (after all, everything's a resource!)

Comment: I could not appreciate more about your detailed explanation. EXCELLENT!